Salesforce scratch org automation within an existing Github project and folder structure settings
I have an application on Salesforce, which I clone on VS code for doing manual testing, after creating scratch org and all.
My next task is to automate the flow within that project using Selenium/ JS.
I am seeking help in setting up the structure of this project. I may find a solution working on an independent automation project, but the requirement is to do it within CircleCI as when unit tests are passed after a commit, so then the automated UI tests could run.
My first question is right on the very first step. How to configure this project structure (folder structure) considering the above existing project setting?
Once the above is through, then my next steps would be to automate the following:

Authorize a devhub
Create a scratch org
Pushing source code on the scratch org
Logging in the scratch org (with handling credentials)

Any immediate help will be highly appreciated.
I am stuck and not able to connect the dots despite doing my extensive online research
